# pairwise comparison of multiple columns with different lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, bioinformatics

I have a table in R with 13 columns and 6k odd rows in total, each column has different lengths. I want to produce a new table where I have compared col1 to col2 and so on and same for col2 to ncol until all columns covered.

The new table's first column should look like something like this if there is a match if not `NA` should be in place of the chromosome location:

```
CTC1vCTC2
chr6:86324663:T>C
```

as an example this is a subsample of the data set i am trying to work on, this is only the first four columns, ideally I want to compare each chromosomal location(and the mutation) and make sure they match exactly:

```
    CTC1    CTC2    CTC3    CTC4
    chr1:2333588:C>T    chr1:902108:C>T chr1:3544992:T>A    chr1:5924518:G>A
    chr1:2938989:G>A    chr1:1262966:C>T    chr1:6021929:G>T          chr1:5965381:C>T
    chr1:3389727:C>T    chr1:1325657:G>A    chr1:6273227:G>A    chr1:6279370:G>C
```

I tried this so far, inspired by the answer below:

```
match_table <- function(table){
  #the output table will have 78 columns
  new_table =data.frame(matrix("NA", nrow = nrow(table), ncol = 78))  
  for(i in ncol(table)){
    for(j in (i+1):ncol(table)){
      for (k in nrow(table)){
        if(table[k,i] == table[k,j] && !is.null(table[k,i])){
          new_table[k,i] <- table[k,i]
        } 
        else if(is.na(table[k,i])){
          new_table[k,i]='N'
        }
      }
      }
  }
  return(new_table)
}
```

This returns the following error:

`Error in if (table[k, i] == table[k, j] && !is.null(table[k, i])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I am probably missing something obvious, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in the first paragraph you are saying you want to compare columns. In the second paragraph, you are saying you want to compare rows. I think I am missunderstanding something. Try to write an example of what you want, it is gonig to be easier to help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Please narrow down your question. As it stands, you're asking for a lot of things. Show us the data (minimal, simulated perhaps) and the code you've tried so far and where it goes wrong.

Comment: I tried to explain the problem again edited my original question adding more details, hope its clearer now, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a function which takes a list (of length at least 2) of vectors of unequal length (thought of as a list of columns) and returns a data frame which compares columns pairwise, with `NA` where there isn't a corresponding match and the common value when there is. It is either a solution to your problem as is or (more likely) something which could at least give you some ideas:

```
match_columns <- function(columns){
  n <- length(columns)
  max_len = max(unlist(lapply(columns, length)))
  new_cols <- list()
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):n){
      v <- rep(NA,length = max_len)
      for (k in seq(min(length(columns[[i]]), length(columns[[j]])))){
        if(columns[[i]][k] == columns[[j]][k]) v[k] <- columns[[i]][k]
      }
      nm <- paste0("col",i,"vcol",j)
      new_cols[[nm]] <- v
    }
  }
  data.frame(new_cols)
}
```

Comment: This inspired me to write a function which solved my problem!